# Update an InnoSetup Installation - Update Previous Install Dir

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating installers for either full application and patch.

For the full app installer (300MB+), versioning is `x.x.0` (ex. `1.1.0`).
And for the patch (10MB+) it is `x.x.x` (ex. `1.1.1`).

The installation folder is formatted like this: "App Name ".
Example - `App Name 1.1.0`, `App Name 1.1.1`

There should only be 1 version of the app that resides in the machine, so for full version installs - when the app is detected to be previously installed, the existing app is uninstalled first.

So the scenario is like this:

1. User installs a full app - 1.1.0 (OK)

   - Directory `App Name 1.1.0` is created
2. User installs a patch - 1.1.1 (OK)

   - `UsePreviousAppDir=true` so it writes on top of directory `App Name 1.1.0`
   - `App Name 1.1.0` is renamed to `App Name 1.1.1` as part of `CurStepChanged()` when `CurStep` is `ssPostInstall`.
3. User installs a full app - 1.2.0 (NOK - expected to uninstall the prev version 1.1.1 and install this new version 1.2.0)

   - If UsePreviousAppDir is true, directory `App Name 1.1.0` is created. This is because this is what Innosetup remembers as the "previous app" (since we only renamed the patch).
   - If UsePreviousAppDir is false, directory `App Name 1.2.0` is created. And the prev version `App Name 1.1.1` is not uninstalled because the previous install was pointing to `App Name 1.1.0`.

How can I configure my ISS file so that when I do a full install after a patch install, it can still find the renamed directory and uninstall it?

For reference, here is my code for renaming in patch installer:

```
{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
   if (CurStep=ssPostInstall) then begin
    RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}'), ExpandConstant('{app}\..\{#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}'))     
    end;
end;
```

And for my uninstall script (full version):

```
{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;


{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;


{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
{ Return Values: }
{ 1 - uninstall string is empty }
{ 2 - error executing the UnInstallString }
{ 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString }

  { default return value }
  Result := 0;

  { get the uninstall string of the old app }
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

{ ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And my [UninstallDelete] section in the patch installer, in case user wants to uninstall the entire thing:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\..\{#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: Is it important that you keep the version number in the directory name? You only allow one version of the application to be installed at a time, so why not just go with  `App Name` and always keep the directory?

Comment: @PMF - It is quite important as our previous releases have this naming convention and don't really want to change it. Worse comes to worst, then probably that is the only option we have - drop the version number from the directory. But hopefully there is a bright idea somewhere where I could keep the version on.

Comment: What if, when installing a patch, you also set `UsePreviousAppDir=false` and perform a full install? That way, it would fully uninstall everything and do a full upgrade, even if it was (from the user's point of view) only a patch. Of course, this works only if the patch installer is actually the same as a full installer.

Comment: Your actual problem is that you rename the directory. That's wrong. That breaks everything. If you rename the installation directory, the user won't be able to uninstall the application as the uninstall comment in registry won't be pointing to a valid location. All this idea with version in the directory name in wrong. It's still doable though. But you have to take a different approach. Do not rename the directory. Instead just uninstall the previous version when installing a new one. For that there are lots of existing question here (after all, that's what your `UnInstallOldVersion` does).

Comment: @PMF That is a nice idea. However, the full install is about 300MB+ and the patch is only about 10MB. So the bulk of the files are not bundled on the patch installer. I will update my post with this info

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Thanks for your inputs. The only reason I "reuse" (and therefore only rename) the original folder is because I need the bulk of the files there. Full installer is ~300MB and patch is ~10MB only.  Any other ideas you can share?

Comment: Then maybe just remove at least the last digit from the directory. Name it `App Name 1.1` only or `App Name 1.1.X`. That way you can still keep the name for a patch install.

Comment: Proper way would imo be to rename the old folder *before* the installation, instead of renaming the new folder after the installation.

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl! Thank you for your suggestion. When I tried renaming the new folder during ```ssInstall```, this is the behavior: (1) The old folder ```App Name 1.0.0``` is renamed to ```App 1.0.1``` - OK. But then the actual patch is installed in ```App Name 1.0.0```. (2) On next full install, the uninstaller deletes both ```App Name 1.0.0``` and ```App Name 1.0.1``` which is good!  So the only problem I have is.. How can I make the patch install to the renamed folder ```App Name 1.0.1```? Thought of forcing to copy these files to the new folder but it feels hacky. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I suggested that you should *"rename the **old** folder **before** the installation"*.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant renaming the old folder (```App Name 1.0.0```). I tried doing this in ```CurStepChanged``` (```ssInstall```). One more thing I tried is during ```PrepareToInstall```. Same behavior as in my latest comment.

Comment: 1) `CurStepChanged(ssIntall)` might do, but imo `PrepareToInstall` is better. 2) The patch installer will indeed default to the previous installation folder, at the moment the installer is started. Renaming the folder within installer won't change that. You have to update the installation path programmatically (also in `PrepareToInstall`).

Comment: FWIW I agree with Martin that you should not rename the install directory. For best results and the simplest upgrade path, use the same directory name throughout the lifetime of the package that uses that `AppId`.

Comment: If you want to keep the patch small, could you copy everything from the original directory first?